# Synchronized java code performs times faster than unsynchronized one

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization

I work on a high concurrency app. In the app code I try to avoid synchronization where possible. Recently, when comparing test performance of a unsynchronized and synchronized code versions, it turned out synchronized code performed three-four times faster than its unsynchronized counterpart.

After some experiments I came to this test code:

```
private static final Random RND = new Random();
private static final int NUM_OF_THREADS = 3;
private static final int NUM_OF_ITR = 3;
private static final int MONKEY_WORKLOAD = 50000;

static final AtomicInteger lock = new AtomicInteger();

private static void syncLockTest(boolean sync) {
    System.out.println("syncLockTest, sync=" + sync);

    final AtomicLong jobsDone = new AtomicLong();
    final AtomicBoolean stop = new AtomicBoolean();

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_THREADS; i++) {
        Runnable runner;

        if (sync) {
            runner = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (!stop.get()){
                        jobsDone.incrementAndGet();

                        synchronized (lock) {
                            monkeyJob();
                        }

                        Thread.yield();
                    }
                }
            };
        } else {
            runner = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (!stop.get()){
                        jobsDone.incrementAndGet();

                        monkeyJob();

                        Thread.yield();
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        new Thread(runner).start();
    }

    long printTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_ITR;) {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (now - printTime > 10 * 1000) {
            printTime = now;
            System.out.println("Jobs done\t" + jobsDone);
            jobsDone.set(0);
            i++;
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    stop.set(true);
}

private static double[] monkeyJob() {
    double[] res = new double[MONKEY_WORKLOAD];
    for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        res[i] = RND.nextDouble();
        res[i] = 1./(1. + res[i]);
    }
    return res;
}
```

I played with the number of threads, workload, test iterations - each time synchronized code perfomed much faster than unsunchronized one.

Here are results for two different values of NUM_OF_THREADS

> Number of threads:3
>  syncLockTest, sync=true
>  Jobs
>   done  5951
>  Jobs done 5958
>  Jobs done 5878
>  syncLockTest,
>   sync=false
>  Jobs done 1399
>  Jobs done 1397
>  Jobs
>   done  1391
>
> Number of threads:5
>  syncLockTest, sync=true
>  Jobs
>   done  5895
>  Jobs done 6464
>  Jobs done 5886
>  syncLockTest,
>   sync=false
>  Jobs done 1179
>  Jobs done 1260
>  Jobs
>   done  1226

Test environment
    Windows 7 Professional
    Java Version 7.0

Here's a simillar case [Synchronized code performs faster than unsynchronized one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371089/synchronized-code-performs-faster-than-unsynchronized-one)

Any ideas?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/threadlocalrandom.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819638/is-random-class-thread-safe

Comment: I think Gray did a good job answering.  Can he get credit for it?

Answer (score 8):

Random is a thread-safe class.  you are most likely avoiding contention on calls into the Random class by synchronizing around the main job.

Comment: +2 You are right! After making rnd a local variable unsynchronized code perfoms as expected. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

This is fascinating.  I think @jtahlborn nailed it.  If I move the `Random` and make it local to the thread, the times for the non-sync jump ~10x while the `synchronized` ones don't change:

Here are my times with a `static Random RND`:

```
syncLockTest, sync=true
Jobs done   8800
Jobs done   8839
Jobs done   8896
syncLockTest, sync=false
Jobs done   1401
Jobs done   1381
Jobs done   1423
```

Here are my times with a `Random rnd` local variable per thread:

```
syncLockTest, sync=true
Jobs done   8846
Jobs done   8861
Jobs done   8866
syncLockTest, sync=false
Jobs done   25956   << much faster
Jobs done   26065   << much faster
Jobs done   26021   << much faster
```

I also wondered if this was GC related but moving the `double[] res` to being a thread local did not help the speeds at all.  Here's the code I used:

```
...
@Override
public void run() {
    // made this be a thread local but it affected the times only slightly
    double[] res = new double[MONKEY_WORKLOAD];
    // turned rnd into a local variable instead of static
    Random rnd = new Random();
    while (!stop.get()) {
        jobsDone.incrementAndGet();
        if (sync) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                monkeyJob(res, rnd);
            }
        } else {
            monkeyJob(res, rnd);
        }
    }
}
...

private static double[] monkeyJob(double[] res, Random rnd) {
    for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        res[i] = rnd.nextDouble();
        res[i] = 1. / (1. + res[i]);
    }
    return res;
}
```